# Can anyone identify this caterpillar?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Can anyone identify this caterpillar we found on a cauliflower? This was the only photo we could get of it.

Location : Ceres, Fife, Scotland

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us where you found this caterpillar?

Comment: Hi Chris it was found in Ceres, Fife, Scotland. I thought it could perhaps be a Green-veined White caterpillar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might be an [imported cabbageworm](http://urbanfarmsista.com/imported-cabbageworm/):

[image]

or a [green-veined white](http://www.ukbutterflies.co.uk/species.php?species=napi#Larva):

[image]

Both exist where you are, and the former is more common than the latter. I can't tell them apart, but consulting the pages might help.